# SQL delete based on query

Tags: sql, sql-delete

How do I delete all laptops made by a manufacturer that doesn’t make PCs?

I currently have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Device` (
`model` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`speed` double DEFAULT NULL,
`RAM` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`HD` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`list_price` double DEFAULT NULL,
`type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`screen` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`model`,`type`)
);

INSERT INTO `Device` VALUES 
('GATE TOP',2.5,2000,500,1000,'LAPTOP','12'),
('GATE TOWER',2.5,2000,500,1000,'DESKTOP',NULL),
('HELLO TOWER',3.5,8000,1000,1299,'DESKTOP',NULL),
('MACBOOK AIR',2.5,2048,500,599,'LAPTOP','11'),
('MACBOOK PRO',3.5,8000,1000,1299,'LAPTOP','19'),
('PAAP',2.5,2048,500,599,'DESKTOP',NULL),
('TOWER',3,3100,400,2499,'DESKTOP',NULL),
('ULTRA TOWER',6,5000,1000,8999,'DESKTOP',NULL),
('VAIO',2.5,2000,500,569,'LAPTOP','12'),
('VAIO TOWER',2.5,2000,500,569,'DESKTOP',NULL);

CREATE TABLE `Product` (
`manu_Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`model` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 PRIMARY KEY (`manu_Name`,`model`),
 KEY `Product` (`model`),
 CONSTRAINT `Product_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`manu_Name`) 
 REFERENCES `Manufacturer` (`name`),
 CONSTRAINT `Product_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`model`) 
 REFERENCES `Device` (`model`)
);

INSERT INTO `Product` VALUES 
('GATEWAY','GATE TOP'),('GATEWAY','GATE TOWER'),
('ACER','HELLO TOWER'),('APPLE','MACBOOK AIR'),
('APPLE','MACBOOK PRO'),('ACER','PAAP'),
('DELL','TOWER'),('SONY','VAIO'),
('SONY','VAIO TOWER');

CREATE TABLE `Manufacturer` (
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`country` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`phone` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
);

INSERT INTO `Manufacturer` VALUES 
('ACER','TAIWAN','9024801111'),
('APPLE','UNITED STATES','9028189125'),
('DELL','UNITED STATES','9025551234'),
('GATEWAY','UNITED STATES','8705551698'),
('SONY','JAPAN','0123456789'),
('TOSHIBA','JAPAN','1235553560');
```

Comment: Struggling with what?  Are you sure you're trying to delete an `index`?

Comment: you want to delete an index based on a query? What query?

Comment: The query is supposed to be "Delete all laptops made by a manufacturer that doesn’t make PCs"

Comment: And... which manufacturer doesn't make PCs?

Comment: IN these tables APPLE dosen't

Answer (score 1):

The delete statement would be something like this:

```
delete from `Device` where `model` in (
    select `model` from `Product` where `manu_Name` in ('APPLE')
);
```

Comment: Here's a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3d90/1) The delete is on the schema creation side, the shows the device is gone